# Is MySQL the right choice for storing logs?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, nosql

I would like to store/read/process log data that comes from various sensors (e.g temperature, pressure) in 30 second intervals.

The web app will show statistics and summaries of the log data.

Now I am wondering if it would be better to use a NoSQL database in this case?
Or would it be better to store the information in xml files, parse it and calculate average values and other important stats and save those to a database?

Thank you for your tips

Comment: This question belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It totally depends on your architecture and if the data is time crititcal. If it is, XML is out of the question, for my taste anyway, as it would be far more difficult for your sensor's to sync with a file. Again, it depends on your architecture

Comment: How much data will you end up with?  What will your `SELECTs` look like?  I second the vote against XML.

Comment: It is mostly read actions. Data won't be changed after inserting it. Long Term there will be around 250 Million datasets, mostly FLOAT Values that will be selected. However, I need to store aggregated values to deliever those relativley fast in the application. I was thinking of NoSQL-DB's at some point, as I will have to denormalize the db at some point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your workload is a one-two digit number of insertions/updates per 30 seconds and the equal order of magnitude of queries. If I'm right above then MySQL should be fine for your task.